# How to draw a mixing rule? #chemistry

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemistry

I'm writing examples how to calculate a concentration for my students, but I stuck at mixing rule. I thought to draw this by tikz, but I don't have an idea how to do this. It should looks like on this photo.

[image]

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I can only write these equations, but I can't draw in tikz :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion using the `tikz-cd` package/library.

The generic anchor `text right` allows us to add a label to the right of the last column without it messing up the placement of the lines between the cells (which always point to the center of a node).

I'm not defining `\C` globally but only with `install C shortcut` inside the picture as to not overwrite any other `\C` macros.

The commands `\drar`, `\urar` etc. are shortucuts to `\ar[dr]` or `\arrow[dr]` where `d` stands for *d*own and `r` stands for *r*ight. Meaning, `\drar` draws an arrow to the cell down and right of it.

If the lines actually need to land on the most nothern and southern tip of `C` and `m` a little bit more work is necessary.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclaregenericanchor{text right}{%
  \pgf@sh@reanchor{#1}{base}%
  \multiply\pgf@x by 2
}
\makeatother
\tikzcdset{install C shortcut/.code=\newcommand*\C[1]{C_{\%_{##1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  install C shortcut, sep=tiny, arrows={-, gray},
  cells={font=\strut, inner xsep=.2ex, inner ysep=.1ex},
  /tikz/mlabel/.style={label={[anchor=text]text right:{}=|\C{#1}-C_\%|}}
]
\C{1} \drar &        & |[ mlabel = 2 ]| m_{r_1} \dlar \\
               & C_{\%} \\
\C{2} \urar &        & |[ mlabel = 1 ]| m_{r_2} \ular
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. But what should I do if I want to put this into article or beamer? because when I did this, its didn't work.

Comment: @MichałSzymankiewicz You need `\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{cd}` or `\usepackage{tikzcd}`. `tikzcd` loads `tikz` and its own `cd` library.

Comment: Ok, now it work properly. Thank you again :) .